# how to create docker image for a new version of alpine linux which is not available on dockerhub

Tags: alpine-linux

Is there a way to create alpine docker image from scratch for a new version of alpine let's say 3.x.x which is not available on docker hub? All the downloads I see on http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/releases/x86_64/ are iso and not sure how to create rootfs.tar.gz from which the existing docker images in docker hub are created.

Comment: If you are specifically wanting 3.4.6.. when I `docker pull alpine:3.4` and run `docker run -it --rm alpine:3.4 cat /etc/alpine-release` it returns 3.4.6

Comment: 3.4.6 was just an example; what I really want is a way to build my own alpine docker image from scratch. Since alpine is providing us with ISOs I was wondering if there is a way to build a custom base image from that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the downloaded filename is `rootfs.tar.gz` this is what your Dockerfile would be

```
FROM scratch
ADD rootfs.tar.gz /
```

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to download/build rootfs.tar.gz for a version which is not yet available on dockerhub as an image.